# Possible to share USB port for ST-LINK over remote desktop?

Tags: usb, stm32, remote-desktop

Is this possible? Plug STM board into local USB port, configure sharing device under Remote Desktop settings ("Local Resources > More"), then remote into PC running STM debug software and try to access board through ST-LINK via shared USB port? When I try, the software doesn't see the device.

This sort of thing works with other shared devices (drives, etc), but the STM software doesn't see this particular device. The device is visible locally before I open remote desktop.

Comment: what for? ------

Comment: @P__J__ : To program the board. STM board is physically attached to computer A, but software is on computer B. Would like to remote into B from A to use the software to program the board.

Answer (score 2):

Your apprach is wrong.

Connect the STM on the target machine. Run OpenOCD on that machine and connect via TCP from your local machine.

It is called remote debugging. 
No USB magic

Comment: Okay, will check into this (+1). Will accept your answer if this works, thanks for the tip